# Lightning Web Components, How to include a static resource in an unlocked package?

Tags: lightning-web-components, static-resources, unlocked-package

We are wanting to add a static resource file to an unlocked package for a learning project.  It is a JS file that we would like to add to the static resources.  Can we include that with a package install?  We aren't sure the right way to do it. We would like to install it with the package, rather than instructing the next admin to install it (upload it in Setup to Static Resources) separately as part of installation process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

[image]
add to org then retrieve static resources folder in package.xml.

[image]